# Targeting specific JavaScript object instance from flash

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

Greetings, first time poster.
Let's say a have flash(swf) object on my page, and I have a specific JavaScript class (lets call it "JSClass")that works with that flash object.
JavaScript class has some methods for communicating with the flash object.
When the flash object is embedded in to page via swfObject , I create an instance of the JSClass , and give it the id of the flash object on the page , so that instance can specifically communicate with that flash object.
I have more than one same flash file on the page, and I need to differentiate calls to specific flash objects.
Something like this:

```
var flashControl1 = new JSClass('flash_id_1');
var flashControl2 = new JSClass('flash_id_2');

// so later I can start the first flash object
flashControl1.startAnimation();

// and stop animation on the second flash object
flashControl2.stopAnimation();
```

That all works fine.
The problem that I'm having is that, flash objects need to do some stuff internally before they can be manipulated via JavaScript ( they need to load in some stuff etc...)

Flash objects need to notify the instances of the JSClass that are referencing them, that they are ready to be manipulated.
something like this.

```
  
flashControl1.onFlashReady = function()  
{  
// do some stuff here when the flash is ready.  
}
```

How can I call "flashControl1.onFlashReady()" from flash?
Note that flash doesn't know which JSCLass instance to target.
How can target particular JSClass instances from flash object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you pass the `flash_id` via flashvars to your flash movies and when a flash movies' initailization is done you use `ExternalInterface.call("someJsMethod", flashId);` to notify your javascript. In your javascript method `someJsMethod(flashId)` you can then check the id and map it to your JSClass.

Comment: On a second though, the suggested solution will work for this particular problem. 
But there is still a more general problem of referencing OOP JavaScript from within flash.